# Perl error in MySQL and DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I'm a student of bioinformatics and I am using the OrthoMCL tool using this command

```
./orthomclLoadBlast my_orthomcl/orthomcl.config my_orthomcl/similarSequence.txt
```

but I am getting the error

> Can't connect to data source ' :mysqllocalinfile=1' because I can't
>   work out what driver to use (it doesn't seem to contain a
>   'dbi:driver:' prefix and the DBI_DRIVER env var is not set) at
>   /home/linux/Desktop/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9/bin/../lib/perl/OrthoMCLEngine/Main/Base.pm
>   line 56

`DBI` is already installed in my system, so why is it giving this error? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need database *drivers* to be installed for the `DBI` module to work with your database.  In this case it looks like you need to install [`DBD::mysql`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::mysql).

It is possible that OrthoMCL omits the driver name and uses just `dbi::`, in which case you must set the environment variable `DBI_DRIVER` to `mysql`.

The proper answer must be in the documentation for OrthoMCL. Have you read it?

---

**Update**

Looking at the [source for `orthomclLoadBlast`](https://www.cbil.upenn.edu/svn/apidb/OrthoMCLEngine/branches/2.0-bundle-msh/Main/bin/orthomclLoadBlast) it looks like your config file is faulty. There is a chance that someone here is familiar with the utility, but you must publish `orthomcl.config` to stand a chance of getting any useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

you should use mysql for the driver:

sample:

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:DBNAME','root','password')
```

Comment: The OP is running `orthomclLoadBlast` as a utility. The `DBI->connect` is beyond his acccess